# How to get a list of files names from Snowflake external S3 stage?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for the best way to automatically detect new files in a S3 bucket and then to load the data into a Snowflake table.

I know this can be achieved using Snowpipe and SNS, SQS notifications set up in AWS but I would like to have a self-contained solution within Snowflake which can be used for multiple data sources.

I want to have a table which is updated with the file names from a S3 bucket and then to load files which have not already been loaded from S3 into Snowflake.

The only way I have found to automatically detect new files from an external S3 stage in Snowflake so far is to use the code below and a task on a set schedule. This lists the file names and then uses result_scan to display the last query as a table.

```
list @STAGE_NAME;
set qid=last_query_id();
select "name" from table(result_scan($qid))
```

Does anyone know a better way to automatically detect new files in an external stage from Snowflake? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: As far I know, it's the only way.

Comment: Snowipipe and using tasks along with the result_scan are the only ways!

Comment: Thanks! One concern I have on this approach is how to ensure the last query run is always the list statement. Would putting this in a procedure ensure it always captures the correct ID? Have you run into any difficulties when combining this with tasks and procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily better than the way you've already found, but there is an alternative approach to listing the files in an S3 bucket.

If you create an [EXTERNAL TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html) over the data in S3, you can then use the [METADATA$FILENAME](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata.html) property in a query. If you have a record of which files have already been loaded into Snowflake then you can compare and select the names of the new files and process them.

e.g.

```
ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE MYSCHEMA.MYEXTERNALTABLE REFRESH;

SELECT DISTINCT
   METADATA$FILENAME as filename
FROM 
   MYSCHEMA.MYEXTERNALTABLE;
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! Would I be correct in thinking for large amounts of data stored in an external stage querying this data in an external stage would require a lot more Snowflake compute resource than using the list command and selecting from the last query run?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect there wouldn't be much difference if any as both approaches probably use the same underlying metadata.

Comment: Also remember a stage is a reference to an s3 path, which could potentially contain data for more than one table or entity.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Run:

#### Your approach

You've already found a viable solution, and your concern about the reliability of the last query id function is understandable. Procedures' sessions are isolated and so the last_query_id() function will be isolated to only the statements executed within that procedure. It might be unnecessary to use a procedure, but I personally like that they let you create reusable abstractions.

#### Another approach

An alternative, if you don't like the approach you're using, would be to create a single table with a single VARIANT data column plus the stage metadata columns, maintained by a single giant pipe, and you could maintain a set of materialized views over that table, which would filter, convert variant fields to columns, and sanitize, as appropriate.

There are some benefits:

- **simpler:** integrating new prefixes for a stage requires only an additional materialized view, not an additional pipe + task
- **more control:** you'd be able to operate directly and automatically on the data in raw form, rather than needing to load into a table and then check it. This means you can perform data quality checks, metadata checks, and sanitization.
- **maintainable:** the use of materialized views over an immutable source means you can at any time change the logic and perform a full backfill with little effort.

## Long Run:

[Notification Integrations](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-notification-integration.html) enable snowflake to listen (and possibly notify in the future, roadmap-gods willing) to external messaging systems. At this moment only Azure is supported, so it won't work for your case, but keep an eye out over the next few months -- I think it's safe to speculate that we will see this feature grow to support AWS, and a more direct and concise manner for implementing your original solution will eventually become available.