# Snowflake stored procedure - loop through csv files in AWS S3 and COPY INTO tables with same name

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was wondering if someone could help me with the error message I am getting from Snowflake. I am trying to create a stored procedure that will loop through 125 files in S3 and copy into the corresponding tables in Snowflake. The names of the tables are the same names as the csv files. In the example I only have 2 file names set up (if someone knows a better way than having to list all 125, that will be extremely. helpful) .

The error message I am getting is the following:

> Syntax error line 5 at position 11 unexpected '1'.
> Syntax error line 6 at position 22 unexpected '='. (line 4)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE load_data_S3(file_name VARCHAR,table_name VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1 to 2 LOOP
CASE i
WHEN 1 THEN
SET file_name = 'file1.csv';
SET table_name = 'FILE1';
WHEN 2 THEN
SET file_name = 'file2.csv';
SET table_name = 'FILE2';
--WILL LIST THE REMAINING 123 WHEN STATEMENTS
 ELSE
 -- Do nothing
 END CASE;
 COPY INTO table_name
 FROM @externalstg/file_name 
FILE_FORMAT = (type='csv');
END LOOP;
RETURN 'Data loaded successfully';
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to list the files in a stage (see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248493/how-to-get-a-list-of-files-names-from-snowflake-external-s3-stage)). You can loop through the resultset and run COPY INTO on each record